# How to place three divs side by side inside another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create three divs side by side such that, I want to inplement virtual lightbox in each div for a different set of pics. Now I have tried so much but I'm not able to create one.
Below is the code -

```
            <div id="content-4">

                           <!--main content-->
      <div>
        <h3><span>Jumbo Events</span> </h3>

        <!-- About company -->
                    <div style="">

                        <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">first</div>
  <div id="second">second</div>
  <div id="third">third</div>
</div>


</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $VisualLightBoxParams$ = {autoPlay:true,borderSize:21,enableSlideshow:true,overlayOpacity:0.4,startZoom:true};
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="visuallightbox.js"></script>


   </div>
```

Below is the style for each -

```
   #wrapper {
  width:1000px;
  clear:both;
}
#first {
  background-color:red;
  width:310px;
  height: 240px;
  float:left;
}
#second {
  background-color:blue;
  width:310px;
  height:240px
  float:left;
}
#third {
  background-color:#bada55;
  width:310px;
  height:240px;
  float:left;
}
#content-4
{
        height:325px;
        width:1016px;
        margin:5px auto ;
        background-color:#FFFFCC ;
        padding:18px ;
        margin-left:2px ;
        border:1px solid #C8C8C8;
        border-collapse:collapse;

}
```

Now, with the above code I see that each of the divs are placed one below the other.

Comment: my dear look to my answer, it been tested!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a missing `;` in `#second`.

Here's the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xfeu7/2/).

Comment: It works with block elements - that's a botch, not a fix.  I've updated your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Xfeu7/1/

Comment: and you just copy pasted my answer?

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error in your css you missed a `;` if you fix that it'll work [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XRy3s/)

```
#second {
  background-color:blue;
  width:310px;
  height:240px;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using CSS display `in-line block` - for example:

```
.wrapper div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: As a wise man once said - there is a way of doing things, and a way of getting things done.

Comment: He clearly wouldn't have used the above CSS if he was wise.  He would have fixed the incorrect CSS instead.

Comment: Your answer is useless since OP's problem is a syntax error, when fixed solves the problem at hand.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut an easy thing to miss, i'm sure st peter will forgive me when i reach the pearly gates.